# How do I get a SVN checkout using a Public/Private key pair?

Tags: svn, ssh, key

I have to check some code and run it. I have the URL:

```
svn+ssh://myuser@www.myclient.com/home/svn/project/trunk
```

I have a file with their private key. What do I do to get this code?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Mac OS X Leopard locally, but this is really supposed to go on a RH ES4 box.

Comment: I am also getting "-bash: svn+ssh://... blah blah No such file or directory", though I have svn and ssh installed and use them all the time. Can I do this from Eclipse with Subclipse plugin (which I also use alot)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The private key goes on the client machine, often named as `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, or `~/.ssh/identity` depending on the SSH version and the type of key.  However, you can just use `ssh -i path/to/private.key`.

This is presuming that the corresponding public key exists on the server in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and that your local machine is running the OpenSSH client.  If you are using PuTTY on Windows, simply open up the Pageant program, and import the key via the GUI.

Comment: this question is asking for svn, not ssh

Answer (score 59):

If you need to use a custom key just for svn, the following will work:

`SVN_SSH="ssh -i /path/to/key_name"`

`export SVN_SSH`

`svn commands`

http://labs.kortina.net/2010/01/30/svn-checkout-with-private-key-over-ssh/

Comment: Note that I would always use a full path for the path to the key.

Comment: The path is now absolute!

Comment: its usable if only one repository server use, for multiple repository servers need ~/.ssh/config file use

Comment: Works with **Maven** release goal on svn+ssh hosted projects.

Answer (score 15):

Add this entry to your **~/.ssh/config** file:

```config
Host YOUR_SERVER
IdentityFile YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH # (ex: ~/.ssh/rsa)
User USER_NAME
```

For more options, [see the ssh_config man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

Answer (score 8):

just use ssh-add command (it will ask your for your password, this is the password you used when you created this public private key pair ).

```
ssh-add PATH_TO_YOUR_PRIVATE_JEY
e.g. ssh-add ~/.ssh/myPrivateKey.key
```

verify that you added the key correctly by doing this

```
ssh-add -l
```

That will list all identity files it is using.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers two screen shots from Eclipse 3.7 with Subversive.

---

[image: General settings]
**Enter the user name!** (I have forgotten this before taking the screen shot). Do **not** enter a password.

---

[image: SSH Settings]
Enter the key passphrase if you private key is passphrase protected.

---

*A picture is worth a thousand words.*

Answer (score 1):

Add the private key to your `~/.ssh/` folder and then run `ssh-agent $SHELL; ssh-add;`, and then the `svn co` of that URL should work.

Comment: Your private keys _do not_ go in ~/.ssh/config.

Comment: Oops, you're totally right, that should have been `authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that I used to connect from the Mac OS X command line to my server via svn+ssh:

On server:

```
ssh-keygen -b 1024 -t dsa -f mykey   (creates mykey and mkey.pub files)
```

Copy contents of **mykey.pub** to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys  (create authorized_keys file if it doesn't exist)

Download **mkey** to your local machine and run:

```
chmod 600 mkey  (the next step won't run otherwise)
svn-add mkey  (enter your passphrase)
```

checkout from your svn server with ssh:

```
svn co svn+ssh://user@server.com/repos/path
```

Delete mkey and mkey.pub from your server

Comment: never heard of "svn-add" esp one that takes a passphrase, think you are referring to ssh-add

Answer (score 0):

```
SVN_SSH="ssh -i /xxx/xxx/id_rsa" svn checkout svn+ssh://username@svn.xxx.com/data
```