# phpStorm SVN public key

Tags: svn, phpstorm

I'm trying to connect to SVN repository from phpStorm. I managed to define repository url, but if I choose checkout, it need authentication - username and password. I'm using username and public key to authenticate but I can't find out where to set the key. Could you please help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Go to File / Settings / Version Control / Subversion

Uncheck 'Use command line client'.

Click 'Clear Auth Cache' then 'Apply'.

Go to VCS / Checkout From Version Control / Subversion

Choose your repository.

PhpStrom should now ask you for your credentials.

Comment: Thank you @Robin_. It asked me before. But I still cannot log in -> I cannot set my private key - when I do Checkout, it want only username and password, but where should I set private key?

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192134/how-do-i-get-a-svn-checkout-using-a-public-private-key-pair

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue with PHPStorm the thing is if you work on Windows (Win10 in my case )that you need to have your SVN_SSH enviroment variable defined otherwise PHPStrom will not know where to take those public keys from and it switches to the classic username password authentication (use it in same configuration with Tortoise Plink and keys generated by Putty).